# Counting lines in case statement in SQL

Tags: sql, count, case

I am trying to get the lines count(entered) for Today, Month to date, year to date in one sql statement query. but I am not sure why it is giving me the same values for all the the three.
here is my sql statement.

```
select BU,
count(CASE when a.date_added = trunc(sysdate) then (part) else '0' end) 
as TodayQuotes,
count(CASE when a.date_added > last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)) then (part) else '0'     end) 
as MTDQuotesValue,
COUNT(case when to_number(to_char(a.date_added,'yyyy'))='2011' then (part) else '0' end) 
as YTDRegularValue
from articles
group by BU;
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why convert `to_char`, then `to_number`, and eventually compare to a string (`'2011'`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `"else '0'"` from your `CASE` expressions (there is an implicit `ELSE NULL`)

`COUNT` counts all `NOT NULL` values and `'0'` is `NOT NULL` and so contributes to the `COUNT`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select BU,
       sum(CASE when a.date_added = trunc(sysdate) 
                then 1 
                else 0 
            end ) as TodayQuotes,
       sum(CASE when a.date_added > last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)) 
                then 1 
                else 0 
            end) as MTDQuotesValue,
       sum(case when to_number(to_char(a.date_added,'yyyy'))='2011' 
                then 1 
                else 0 
            end) as YTDRegularValue
  from articles
 group by BU;
```